# .htaccess rewriting won't work or gets overwritten

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url that needs to get rewritten with .htaccess
For example I'm gonna use a news section of a website.

```
www.example.com/news/               -works
www.example.com/news/latest/        -works
www.example.com/news/1/this-is-news -does not work
```

This is a section of my current .htaccess that is used for the "news" section.

```
RewriteRule ^news/? index.php?view=news [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=news&task=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=news&id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your last entry:

```
^news/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]*$
```

it'll fix it so that any numbers, letter, dashes in the last slash will be caught, so it'll match your example, at least.